# Bash: Remove all occurring pattern except 1

Tags: bash, sed

I need to remove all occurring patterns except 1, but I haven't been able to get this working in a Bash script.
I tried

```
sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' -e 's/\\ / /1'
```

and

```
sed ':a;s/\([^ ]* .*[^\\]\) \(.*\)/\1\\ \2/;ta'
```

but neither do have the desired effect unfortunately.

Is someone able to help me out?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Your first attempt seems to do exactly what you want.  So you ought to provide more details about what you want.

Comment: Maybe you want `sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' -e '1,/ /s/\\ / /'`

Comment: My apologies, the pattern which it should remove is `PasswordAuthentication no`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no sample input, I will just guess and maybe it will help:

```
 cat file

header for file
1111
header for file
1111
2222
header for file
3333
4444
5555

awk '/header/&&c++>0 {next} 1' file

header for file
1111
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
```

Though I am not the greatest in `sed`

```
sed '1!{/^header/d;}' file
```

Comment: All it does is list the entire file I need to search the pattern for but doesn't actually apply it. Would you mind letting me know how I can actually apply the changes?

Comment: Can you please show your input and desired output, without them I am guessing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove duplicated white spaces?

If this is correct try
    sed -e 's/  +/ /g'

The problem using * is that it match also 0 occurring patterns, you have to use + instead.

Best regards, Georg

Comment: I'm trying to remove `PasswordAuthentication no` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config